# Events and delegates - new event for different method output

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Just going through understanding events and delegates and I have a question regarding outputting a different string using the same event and delegate and if it possible. Take this example.

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Publisher b = new Publisher();
            Subscriber a = new Subscriber(b);

            b.OnLog("12");
        }
    }

     class Publisher 
    {
        public delegate void LogHandler(string message);

        public event LogHandler Log;


        public void OnLog(string message)
        {
            //Fire the event - notifying all subscribers
            if (Log != null)
                Log(message);
        }
    }

    class Subscriber 
    {
        public Subscriber(Publisher pub)
        {
            //Where B is used - subscribe to it's public event
            pub.Log += new Publisher.LogHandler(HandleSomethingHappening);
            pub.Log += new Publisher.LogHandler(HandleSomethingHappeningStop);
        }

        public void HandleSomethingHappening(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }

        public void HandleSomethingHappeningStop(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Here, both methods

`HandleSomethingHappening` and `HandleSomethingHappeningStop` will output "12". If I wanted `handleSomethingHappeningStop` to output, lets say "24", do I need to create a new event associated with the same delegate to do this?

so for example

```
pub.LogOutput24 += new Publisher.LogHandler(HandleSomethingHappeningStop);
```

Thanks

Comment: IMO, _yes!_ You're associating one publisher with two subscriber, then ofourse both would get the same value that was broadcasted.

Comment: Thanks, I just was anxious that creating many events wouldn't be the correct design pattern, but this makes sense.

Comment: Subscribing an event more than once in the same class is a code smell.   Do keep in mind that the order in which your event handlers run is undefined.  Pretty important to make up your mind what you are going to do with the event notification.  You for example get the exact same outcome with just one event handler that calls Console.WriteLine() twice.  And are then more likely to notice that it doesn't make much sense to do that.

Comment: @HansPassant - You stated 'Subscribing an event more than once in the same class is a code smell' - interesting, is it more perceived to have ONLY one subscription per class? 

I guess I am querying more on "why use events that are subscribed in a different class" instead of "What is an event".. I realise your not my teacher so any good material on this that you know, free or pay, let me know and I be grateful!